# How to get a substring from the beginning till the end of a word that starts with a with a given substring - Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I'm trying to get a substring from the beginning till the end of a word that begins with some string.

For example:

```
a = "Metrics testSomeMetrics gets initial metrics data"
```

I also have a string that is a substring of `a`.

For example:

`b = "test"`.

`"test"` appears in the second word of the string `a`.

I need to return a substring from the beginning of `a` till the end of the word with `test` 
 in it.

In this example I need to return: `"Metrics testSomeMetrics"`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What should the output be for `a = "foo testbar hello testworld data"`? Containing two words starting with `"test"` or can we assume that scenario doesn't occur?

Comment: It can occur. Should return `foo testbar`.

Comment: You awarded the greenie to an incorrect answer.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to see evidence of your effort. As is you gave us some data and told us the result you want, but it looks like you want us to write the code to solve the problem. Also, the string you're trying to parse looks suspiciously like the result of incorrectly scraping a page. If so, your question should be asking how to scrape, not untangle a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Regexp:

```
a = 'Metrics testSomeMetrics gets initial metrics data'
b = 'test'
a.match(/^.*#{b}\w*/).to_s
```

Where:

- `^` — start of the string.
- `.*` — zero or more of any single character.
- `#{b}` — your string.
- `\w*` — zero or more of any word character.

UPDATE

Add `\b` to get `/^.*\b#{b}\w*/` so that it `b` will be exactly a start of a new string.

Comment: `b` must be [escaped](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) for use inside regular expressions

Comment: also, it should be "a word that *begins* with some string"

Comment: Getting a substring is better achieved with `string[regex]` instead of `string.match(regex).to_s`.

Comment: Thanks @yzalavin and @Jack. At the end I used `a.match(/^.*\b(b\w*)\w*/i).to_s`. That worked for me.

Comment: @bazron It seems that `a[/^.*?\b#{Regexp.escape(b)}\w*/i]` would work better for you, because otherwise it would return up until the _last_ word that starts with "test"

Comment: Let `r = /^.*#{b}\w*/ #=> /^.*test\w*/ `. Then  `"Twotestcycles"[r] #=> "Twotestcycles"` and `"Twotestcycles testMetrics testMore"[r] #=> "Twotestcycles testMetrics testMore"`, neither of which are correct.

Comment: Thank you @Jack. That worked. It now returns till after the first occurrence of "test".

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find a regular expression that works here. One could do the following, however:

```
def get_juicy_bit(str, word)
  str.match(/\b#{word}\S+/) { |md| str[0...md.end(0)] }
end
```

```
word = "test"
```

```
get_juicy_bit("Metrics testSomeMetrics gets data", word)
  #=> "Metrics testSomeMetrics" 
get_juicy_bit("Metrics     testSomeMetrics gets data", word)
  #=> "Metrics     testSomeMetrics" 
get_juicy_bit("Metrics donottestMetrics gets data", word)
  #=> nil 
get_juicy_bit("testMetrics gets data", word)
  #=> "testMetrics" 
get_juicy_bit("   testMetrics gets data", word)
  #=> "   testMetrics"
```

See [MatchData#end](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-end). The regular expression `/\b#{word}\S+/` reads, "match a word break (`\b`) followed by the value of he variable `word` followed by one or more characters other than whitespace". Here a word break is a character other than a word character (a letter, digit or underscore) or the beginning of the string.

Comment: You can pass a block to `match`: `str.match(/\b#{word}\S+/) { |md| str[0...md.end(0)] }`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I didn't know `match` could take a block, but it avoids the need to check if the `MatchData` object is `nil`, so I'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is:

First, split your string into a array of words. Then find the index of first word that includes the pattern. Finally from the found index create a sub-string of the original (start from 0 to the found index).

```
a = "Metrics testSomeMetrics gets initial metrics data"
b = "test"
words = a.split(" ")

index = words.find_index { |word| word.include?(b) }
return "" unless index

words.slice(0..index).join(" ")
```

Comment: You should use `word.start_with? b` instead

Comment: A possible complaint is that two words separated by multiple spaces will be replaced the the same words separated by one space.